# Office-js - set icon to mailbox.item

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is there way to set/change Mailbox.Item (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.9#item) icon or anyhow mark Mailbox.Item from Office.Context so it is clearly visible from the overview?

[image]

I have searched the internet and found solutions that do not include Office-js at all. Maybe some workaround with setting Messageclass via EWS call and creating FormRegion, but I need it to be done via the Office-js web add-in.

This is the best lead I found
[Can i add custom icon to "outlook" item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132296/can-i-add-custom-icon-to-outlook-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the Graph api, you can add an extended property. You can only see this icon in an Outlook installed on Windows. Code in js:

```
const data = {
    singleValueExtendedProperties: [
        id: 'Integer 0x1080',
        value: '265' // or another number
    ]
};

request.patch(`/me/messages/${messageId}`, data);
```

Comment: I could not find any sensible documentation for this. This is exactly what I needed! the issue needs to be implemented within days so you are my saviour!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Hourglasser I glad I could help, even if I'm 5 years late... The extended properties are well documented in graph api docs. You can find all the codes you can use here https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-OXPROPS/%5bMS-OXPROPS%5d.pdf (icon is in p.270). Possible icons are here https://davton.com/blog/changing-the-icon-for-an-outlook-message/ although this list may not be accurate since "255" is shown in "330"

Answer (score 1):

OfficeJS doesn't provide anything for that. But you may try to call EWS from your web add-in, see [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) for more information, where you could set up the `PR_ICON_INDEX` property value. For example, here is the C# sample code which uses Exchange Web Services for setting up an icon:

```
ItemIdType iiItemId = new ItemIdType();
iiItemId.Id = miMailboxItem.ItemId.Id;
iiItemId.ChangeKey = miMailboxItem.ItemId.ChangeKey;
// Create an object of update item type
UpdateItemType updateItemType = new UpdateItemType();
updateItemType.ConflictResolution = ConflictResolutionType.AlwaysOverwrite;
updateItemType.MessageDisposition = MessageDispositionType.SaveOnly;
updateItemType.MessageDispositionSpecified = true;
updateItemType.ItemChanges = new ItemChangeType[1];
ItemChangeType changeType = new ItemChangeType();
changeType.Item = iiItemId;
changeType.Updates = new ItemChangeDescriptionType[1];
// Create a set item field to identify the type of update
SetItemFieldType setItemEmail = new SetItemFieldType();
PathToExtendedFieldType PR_ICON_INDEX = new PathToExtendedFieldType();
PR_ICON_INDEX.PropertyTag = "0x1080";
PR_ICON_INDEX.PropertyType = MapiPropertyTypeType.Integer;
ExtendedPropertyType miMailIcon = new ExtendedPropertyType();
miMailIcon.ExtendedFieldURI = PR_ICON_INDEX;
miMailIcon.Item = "261";
MessageType mtMessage = new MessageType();
mtMessage.ExtendedProperty = new ExtendedPropertyType[1];
mtMessage.ExtendedProperty[0] = miMailIcon;
setItemEmail.Item = PR_ICON_INDEX;
setItemEmail.Item1 = mtMessage;
changeType.Updates[0] = setItemEmail;
updateItemType.ItemChanges[0] = changeType;
// Send the update item request and receive the response
UpdateItemResponseType updateItemResponse = esb.UpdateItem(updateItemType);
```

Comment: Thank you @Eugene Astafiev. Browsing for an answer, I hit PR_ICON_INDEX as well, but I am afraid if it cannot be changed to another icon by Outlook itself - I will have to do deeper research on it, how it behaves, and then go through EWS call (probably via makeEwsRequestAsync method). 

Another alternative that I think of is to create a new master category on Mailbox and set that category to Mailbox.Item, but I will have to do more research as well. 

I appreciate your answer a lot, thanks. If it will be my final solution I will accept it ;)

Comment: A category can help marking an item with a color, not icon.

Comment: Yeah true, but could be enough in my case in order to mark mail - however it is workaround that use current office-js library possibility and it was pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Even I found your answer helpful, I will mark as accepted the down below from @Outlook Add-ins Team MSFT- Office-js does not support out-of-the-box icon setting on items. I will use Categories workaround I described above as product owner approved it. Thanks a lot. Your answer might fully serve/help other people here :)

Comment: I have stated that in the first sentence!

Comment: > OfficeJS doesn't provide anything for that.

Comment: Yeah, true. Sorry :) Changed Accepted to yours, the other is just offical

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the feature to set the icon for the Outlook item, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Added request :)

Comment: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/42941799-set-the-icon-custom-for-the-outlook-item