# VSTO Outlook: Add new icon to the Outlook items shown in the explorer email list

Tags: outlook, icons, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

On folder selection (Inbox, Deleted, Sent, etc.) the Outlook email items are shown listed in the explorer view as a list of Outlook items.

For each Outlook items, some icons (attach, etc.) are show on the right. How can I add new icons there for each outlook item? I want to do the same as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63132296/1624552) or [here](https://davton.com/blog/changing-the-icon-for-an-outlook-message/), but instead of changing an existing one, I would like to add a new one/s.

Additionally (this is optional) it would be great if I could execute some code when user clicks on it but I am ok if I can just show it.

UPDATE 05/10/2022
There are two posibilities:

1. Add new columns to the message grid preview in the explorer view, I mean put more columns at the beginning or after the last column (flag one). This view is obtained when you resize the width of the messages grid:

[image]

2. Use the existing last column of the messages grid preview, marked with a flag, and put there more icons with its click event handlers.

[image]

Is it possible to implement both above solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trivial way to inject custom icons there. The best what you could do is to use the [PR_ICON_INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagiconindex-canonical-property) property with a set of predefined icons. The property contains a number that indicates which icon to use when you display a group of email objects.

As explained in the articles mentioned in your post you can use the [PropertyAccessor.SetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.setproperty) to set up an icon for Outlook items.

> Additionally (this is optional) it would be great if I could execute some code when user clicks on it but I am ok if I can just show it.

You can handle the [SelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selectionchange) event of the `Explorer` class which is fired when the user selects a different or additional Microsoft Outlook item programmatically or by interacting with the user interface. The Outlook object model doesn't provide any other events for that.

Comment: I am not referring to inject custom icons to replace the existing ones that are shown, instead what I want is to place there new icons next to the existing ones. Is that possible? Using PropertyAccessor.SetProperty to set the PR_ICON_INDEX of an Outlook item, I guess that the only you do is to replace the existing icon for another, but you don't add a new icon, right? If it is possible but it is not trivial, could you tell me how? From your answer It is not clear for me if I can add a new icon or not.

Comment: You are on the right avenue - there is no way to add a new column with custom icons in the grid.

Comment: Oh my God! Many things come to my mind: Why there is so much things that cannot be done with this technology (VSTO)? Why is it a technology so limitated? Why Microsoft did this? Why Microsoft does not update VSTO to include more features or levels of customization? Is VSTO definitely abandoned by Microsoft? 98% of things I want to do always end up with a: cannot be done, Outlook VSTO API does not provide any mechanism to do such things. Anyway, a lot of thanks Eugene for given me always support.

Comment: Do you know some kind of technology that extends the Outlook Object model and make possible to do this kind of things? If any, which one do you recommend.

Comment: There is no other technology, you may try playing with Windows API by subclassing Outlook windows, but that is the last resort nobody will be able to help you with that I think.

Comment: I have found below: https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=11396
In fact what I want is to show another column in the explorer view where it is shown all the list of emails for the current folder selected (for example, inbox folder) and put there a custom icon which is mine. I have not tried yet.

Comment: In that case you need to use the PR_ICON_INDEX property for a separate column.

Comment: So then It's possible? I'll try it. I guess all the Outlook items must be set with this same property, otherwise i will not work, right?

Comment: It is possible to have a new column with the PR_ICON_INDEX property value. The number is images are limited and defined by numbers/constants available for that. You can't add custom icons (read your own) outside from the list possible.

Comment: Yep, I was referring to add a new column/s to messages grid in the explorer view where it is shown columns such as From, Subject, Received, Size, Categories, Mention, etc. Add new ones to the beginning or to the end (after flag column) (Option 1 in the updated post). Or also to add more icons with their click event handlers to the last column (flag column) of the messages grid (option 2 in the updated post), next to the existing default Outlook icons trash, flag, etc.  See my updated post I have attached an screenshot.

Comment: You can't put custom/your icons to the grid. But you may add predefined icons to beginning or end of grid in Outlook as I described in my post (see the PR_ICON_INDEX property).

Comment: And how to tell Outlook that you want to add a column at the beginning or end of the grid with a predefined icon using PR_ICON_INDEX property? Do you have any code snippet?

Comment: Eugene, the problem of using PR_ICON_INDEX property is that this property is updated by Outlook itself as well when replying, forwarding, etc. messages so I constantly would need to monitor when it happens an overwrite it again with the proper icon again. Another issue that I am currently facing is that I am not able to add a new column to the inbox folder view either using the Add method from the ViewFields object or directly by injecting an XML to CurrentView.XML property.

Comment: See my posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74018517/vsto-outlook-programmatically-add-a-custom-column-of-type-pr-icon-index-to-an-e   and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73990629/vsto-outlook-add-a-new-explorer-column-with-a-predefined-outlook-icon-pr-icon

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to add a new icon next to the old one - the message view in Outlook does not support that level of customization.

The only way to replace a build-in icon with a truly custom one (instead of using one from a few dozen predefined icons) is to create a custom form (even if exposes no customization) and specify an icon for that form. If the message class (`MailItem.MessageClass`) matches that of a custom form, Outlook will show your custom icon. Not ideal at all.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Idem as I have told to Eugene, each time I want to do something with VSTO, I always end up that it cannot be done with a probability of 98%. Do you know any other technology to extend the Outlook Object Model and allow doing this kind of things? Thx.

Comment: Well, try working with other email clients (or any other apps) - you'd be begging to get back to developing with VSTO :-) I don't think you can do it using any other API - the message view in Outlook is not a standard list view common control, so even Win API won't help.

Comment: I have updated my post with screenshots. See what i am trying to do.

Comment: You can add a column to a view, but you cannot display your icon there.

Comment: Any code snippet on how to add a column to the beginning or end of the grid with a predefined Outlook icon?

Comment: You can add a column in the folder view designer in Outlook, then just take a look at the view XML - you can do that in Outlook Spy (I am its author - https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - click Folder, CurrentView , XML