# VSTO Outlook: Add a new explorer column with a predefined Outlook icon (PR_ICON_INDEX)

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to create a new column in explorer. I would like this column to contain one of the predefined Outlook icons using PR_ICON_INDEX.

So I am looping over all Outlook mail items and set their property PR_ICON_INDEX using below method:

```
    private const int OL_PHONE = 0x15D;
    private const string PR_ICON_INDEX = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003";

    private bool SetExtendedPropertyValue(Outlook.MailItem aMailItem, string aProperty, int value)
    {
        Outlook.PropertyAccessor oPropAcc = null;
        try
        {
            oPropAcc = aMailItem.PropertyAccessor as Outlook.PropertyAccessor;
            oPropAcc.SetProperty(aProperty, value);

            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            //Put your own logging here
        }
        finally
        {
            if (oPropAcc != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oPropAcc);
                oPropAcc = null;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

For example, in some point in my code I call this method like below:

```
SetExtendedPropertyValue(mi, PR_ICON_INDEX, OL_PHONE);
```

Also I have replaced the active explorer CurrentView.XML with a custom view but when I call to CurrentView.Apply() after setting the XML I get below exception:

> ```
> The operation failed
> ```

The custom view I am trying to set is below (not working):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view type="table">
    <viewname>myView</viewname>
    <viewstyle>table-layout:fixed;width:100%;font-family:Segoe UI;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:8pt;color:Black;font-charset:0</viewstyle>
    <viewtime>0</viewtime>
    <linecolor>8421504</linecolor>
    <linestyle>3</linestyle>
    <previewlines>1</previewlines>
    <previewlineschangenum>1</previewlineschangenum>
    <ensuredcategoriesfield>1</ensuredcategoriesfield>
    <collapsestate/>
    <rowstyle>background-color:White;color:Black</rowstyle>
    <headerstyle>background-color:#D3D3D3</headerstyle>
    <arrangement>
        <autogroup>1</autogroup>
        <enablexfc>1</enablexfc>
        <collapseclient/>
        <collapseconv/>
        <upgradetoconvchangenum>1</upgradetoconvchangenum>
    </arrangement>
    <column>
        <name>HREF</name>
        <prop>DAV:href</prop>
        <checkbox>1</checkbox>
    </column>
    <column>
        <heading/>
        <prop>http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00020328-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8ff00003</prop>
        <type>i4</type>
        <width>1190</width>
        <style>padding-left:3px;text-align:left</style>
        <editable>0</editable>
        <displayformat>3</displayformat>
        <userheading/>
    </column>
    <column>
        <heading>Categories</heading>
        <prop>urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords</prop>
        <width>50</width>
        <sortable>0</sortable>
        <style>text-align:left;padding-left:3px</style>
        <editable>1</editable>
    </column>
    <column>
        <heading>Mention</heading>
        <prop>urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:outlook#at-me-flag</prop>
        <type>boolean</type>
        <autoresize>0</autoresize>
        <width>50</width>
        <sortable>0</sortable>
        <style>text-align:center;padding-left:3px</style>
        <editable>0</editable>
        <format>boolicon</format>
        <displayformat>3</displayformat>
    </column>
    <column>
        <heading>Status</heading> 
  <prop>http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003</prop>
        <bitmap>1</bitmap>
        <style>padding-left:3px;;text-align:center</style>
        <editable>0</editable>
    </column>
    <groupbydefault>2</groupbydefault>
    <previewpane>
        <visible>1</visible>
        <markasread>0</markasread>
    </previewpane>
</view>
```

However below XML view is working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view type="table">
    <viewname>myView</viewname>
    <viewstyle>table-layout:fixed;width:100%;font-family:Segoe UI;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:8pt;color:Black;font-charset:0</viewstyle>
    <viewtime>0</viewtime>
    <linecolor>8421504</linecolor>
    <linestyle>3</linestyle>
    <previewlines>1</previewlines>
    <previewlineschangenum>1</previewlineschangenum>
    <ensuredcategoriesfield>1</ensuredcategoriesfield>
    <collapsestate/>
    <rowstyle>background-color:White;color:Black</rowstyle>
    <headerstyle>background-color:#D3D3D3</headerstyle>
    <arrangement>
        <autogroup>1</autogroup>
        <enablexfc>1</enablexfc>
        <collapseclient/>
        <collapseconv/>
        <upgradetoconvchangenum>1</upgradetoconvchangenum>
    </arrangement>
    <column>
        <name>HREF</name>
        <prop>DAV:href</prop>
        <checkbox>1</checkbox>
    </column>
    <column>
        <heading/>
        <prop>http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00020328-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8ff00003</prop>
        <type>i4</type>
        <width>1190</width>
        <style>padding-left:3px;text-align:left</style>
        <editable>0</editable>
        <displayformat>3</displayformat>
        <userheading/>
    </column>
    <column>
        <heading>Categories</heading>
        <prop>urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Keywords</prop>
        <width>50</width>
        <sortable>0</sortable>
        <style>text-align:left;padding-left:3px</style>
        <editable>1</editable>
    </column>
    <column>
        <heading>Mention</heading>
        <prop>urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:outlook#at-me-flag</prop>
        <type>boolean</type>
        <autoresize>0</autoresize>
        <width>50</width>
        <sortable>0</sortable>
        <style>text-align:center;padding-left:3px</style>
        <editable>0</editable>
        <format>boolicon</format>
        <displayformat>3</displayformat>
    </column>
    <groupbydefault>2</groupbydefault>
    <previewpane>
        <visible>1</visible>
        <markasread>0</markasread>
    </previewpane>
</view>
```

The difference between both XML views is the following (first view has defined below column and the second hasn't):

```
    <column>
        <heading>Status</heading>
  <prop>http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003</prop>
        <bitmap>1</bitmap>
        <style>padding-left:3px;;text-align:center</style>
        <editable>0</editable>
    </column>
```

So the problem comes with above column definition. It refers to the property PR_ICON_INDEX. It looks like there is something that Outlook does not like.

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what Outlook itself is using:

```
<column>
    <heading>Icon</heading>
    <prop>http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0fff0102</prop>
    <bitmap>1</bitmap>
    <width>18</width>
    <style>padding-left:3px;;text-align:center</style>
    <editable>0</editable>
</column>
```

Comment: What do you mean? The only difference is the heading name (I guess I can put whatever there), the width that I am missing and finally the prop tag for PR_ICON_INDEX, mine is 0x10800003 and yours 0x0fff0102. Are you saying that I am setting the incorrect tag for PR_ICON_INDEX? Is not 0x10800003 ?

Comment: I have changed 0x10800003 by yours 0x0fff0102. Now when I perform Explorer..CurrentView.Apply() or Save() it does not crash but view is not shown for inbox folder nor PR_ICON_INDEX is displayed. Also if I navigate to View tab in Outlook, my new view is not listed there.

Comment: Okay, i think i have understood you. By default Outlook view has the column you have stated, so the only I need to do is assign a predefined Outlook icon to PR_ICON_INDEX property for each Outlook email. The problem of using this property is that it is also used by Outlook itself so this property is constantly updated by Outlook, so if I set a value for this, it is overwritten by Outlook (on reply, forward, etc.) to update Outlook mailitem status and vice-versa, so we need to constantly update this property and it is not viable.

Comment: What I want is to add another column to the existing view of type Icon (PR_ICON_INDEX) which will be mine and set It with one of the predefined Outlook Icons. So is it possible?

Comment: Nope, that is not possible - Outlook only known how to handle its own icon view. You cannot hook it to a different MAPI property.

Comment: No no, I am not saying to use a different MAPI property. I mean use the same MAPI property (PR_ICON_INDEX) but put it in another new column in the view.

Comment: But then two columns will show the same icon. I don't think I understand the use case.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Both columns will always show the same icon (PR_ICON_INDEX) because Outlook itself will be updating it as well so It does not make sense. I didn't think about it. And I wonder if there is some other icon property different from PR_ICON_INDEX for Outlook mailitem that I can use. Is PR_ICON_INDEX the only one that exists for Outlook mailitem?