# Can we add custom icon in mailbox from outlook web add-in office.js

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am not able to add custom icon in outlook mailbox from web add-in.

I need to add custom icon in outlook mailbox from outlook web add-in office.js library as given in below SS

[image: Green Tick Custom Icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature to add a custom icon to outlook mailbox items is not there. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions).Please add your request there and select appropriate labels. Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 0):

Office JavaScript API (`OfficeJS`) doesn't provide anything for setting up item icons.

However, you may consider creating a COM/VSTO add-in where you could set up a low-level MAPI property for displaying an icon for items. The PR_ICON_INDEX property contains a number that indicates which icon to use when you display a group of email objects. This property, if it exists, is a hint to the client. The client application may ignore the value of this property. See [Can i add custom icon to "outlook" item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132296/can-i-add-custom-icon-to-outlook-item) for more information about that.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.